# Oracle sql - join with input parameter

Tags: sql, oracle

Is good practis create join with parameter?

**on :par_emp = e.employees_id**

eg.

```
select a.abc_id, a.year, a.month, :par_emp as emp, 
  e.name_surname as employees,   
  case when a.emp_1 = :par_emp then hours_1 end hours_1,
  case when a.emp_2 = :par_emp then hours_2 end hours_2,
  case when a.emp_3 = :par_emp then hours_3 end hours_3,
  case when a.emp_4 = :par_emp then hours_4 end hours_4,
  case when a.emp_5 = :par_emp then hours_5 end hours_5
From abc a
     left outer join employee e  on :par_emp = e.employees_id
where :par_emp in (a.emp_1, a.emp_2, a.emp_3, a.emp_4, a.emp_5)
order by a.abc_id;
```

Comment: To me, `on e.employees_id = :par_emp` would be more readable. But the whole logic seems odd. You want to display whatever employee is specified in :par_emp`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks weird that you have to outer join the employee table. With appropriate foreign key constraints it would be impossible for an abc row to have an emp_1, emp_2, etc. that does not exist in the employee table.

What I'd expect is that you select the employee and join their abc rows:

```
select
  a.abc_id, a.year, a.month, e.employees_id, e.name_surname as employee_name,   
  case when a.emp_1 = e.employees_id then hours_1 end hours_1,
  case when a.emp_2 = e.employees_id then hours_2 end hours_2,
  case when a.emp_3 = e.employees_id then hours_3 end hours_3,
  case when a.emp_4 = e.employees_id then hours_4 end hours_4,
  case when a.emp_5 = e.employees_id then hours_5 end hours_5
from employee e  
join abc a on e.employees_id in (a.emp_1, a.emp_2, a.emp_3, a.emp_4, a.emp_5)
where e.employees_id = :par_emp
order by a.abc_id;
```

(The data model would be much simpler, did the abc table have one row per employee and not five employees. But then it would be hard to guarantee that a abc has always a maximum of or exactly five employees, of course.)

Answer (score 2):

Yes, you can, there's is nothing wrong with it. The only thing i will suggest is that you should make comments, cause probably you are going to forget with the time, what was that for.

Pd: There is no difference between "left outer join" and "left join"

Comment: I agree about the redundant `outer` keyword, same with `inner`. What type them when they add nothing?

Comment: No, inner is not redundant, in fact is a type of join, one of the most used and important, it brings the common data between the tables that are being compared.

Here you have an example of the types of joins:

https://www.educba.com/types-of-joins-in-sql/

Comment: I know what inner joins are. The keywords "inner" and "outer" are redundant though. You can just use "join" and "left join" etc.

Comment: Yes, first time i saw them i thought it was something else more important, but i wasn't

Answer (score 1):

I'm not strictly averse to it, but in your example you're effectively achieving a cross join - so you should probably just use a cross join.